# Filter Lucene search results under document type

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net, umbraco7

I have a structure like the following

category (Boots)

----itemsForSale (addidas)

category (Socks)

----itemsForSale (long)

Where Boots is the name of the category doctype and Adidas is the name for the itemsForSale doctype etc.

Now if a visitor to the site selects the Boots category from the checkbox options, I pass the id to the search page

The visitor can also search via keyword and min, max price.

That keyword min,max price option works, I just cannot get the search to work so that it only displays items under the parent, i.e Addidas.

I have the following code:

ExamineIndex

```
<add Name="categoryPath"/>
```

OnGatheringNodeData

```
private void SetCustomSearchParameters(object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e)
    {
        var path    = e.Fields["path"];
        path        = path.Replace(",", " ");
        e.Fields.Add("categoryPath", path);
    }
```

And my search is as follows:

```
 //TODO needs to be fixed so that checkbox search can be done
                    query = searchCriteria.Range("bidPrice", paddedLower, paddedHigher, true, true).And().Field("categoryPath",searchCategory).Or().Field("nodeName",searchCategory.Fuzzy()).Or().Field("nodeName", q.Fuzzy()).Or().Field("description", q.Fuzzy());
```

But no results are getting returned, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, I have rebuild the index, but no luck and when searching in the backoffice, my categoryPath is not showing up.

I have read the following http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2011/12/limiting-an-examine-search-to-the-current-site

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/88502-limiting-examine-search-to-one-page-and-its-children

-------------INDEXSET----------------

```
<IndexSet SetName="AuctionSearch" IndexPath="~/App_Data/ExamineIndexes/AuctionSearch">
    <IndexAttributeFields>
      <add Name="id" />
      <add Name="nodeName"/>
      <add Name="updateDate" />
      <add Name="writerName" />
      <add Name="nodeTypeAlias" />
    </IndexAttributeFields>
    <IndexUserFields>
      <add Name="description"/>
      <add Name="image"/>
      <add Name="name"/>
      <add Name="bidPrice" EnableSorting="true" Type="DOUBLE"/>
      <add Name="searchBidPrice" EnableSorting="true" Type="DOUBLE"/>
      <add Name="numberOfBids"/>
      <add Name="category"/>
      <add Name="itemsForSale"/>
      <add Name="bidEndDateTime"/>
      <add Name="categoryPath"/>
    </IndexUserFields>
    <IncludeNodeTypes>
      <add Name="itemsForSale" />
    </IncludeNodeTypes>
  </IndexSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is a `.GroupedOr`, have you tried something like this?

```
query = searchCriteria.Range("bidPrice", paddedLower, paddedHigher, true, true)
    .And().Field("categoryPath",searchCategory)
    .And().GroupedOr(
        new string[] { "nodeName", "nodeName", "description"}
      , new[]{ searchCategory.Fuzzy(), q.Fuzzy(), q.Fuzzy() }
    )
;
```

Comment: Hi @Napoli, thanks for reply, that returns 0 results, for some reason the categoryPath does not show up in the backoffice search even though its added to ExamineIndex.config

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson what does your `<IndexSet />` look like in your ExamineIndex.config file?

Comment: Hi @Napoli I have added IndexSet

Comment: interesting, I have not used `OnGatheringNodeData` (tho i understand it), but the rest looks correct. if you get rid of all your `.Range, .Or`, etc.. and just query off of your `categoryPath` field, do you get categorical results?

Comment: Hi @Napoli I get no results back

Comment: I think I may have an idea, I think `e.Fields` is literally the dictionary of keys to be indexed, however, you may need to use `e.Node.Attribute("path").Value` to get the value.  Have you tried to search "categoryPath" vs "Boots"? ... maybe "categoryPath" is literally the text that is indexed for all. I haven't indexed this way, but this is just me looking at your code again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, all examples online show 'path' as 'path' or create an alias which I did in my case and it did not work

In my case, the filtering of children under the parent could only be done if I use __Path

Working Code

```
query = searchCriteria.Range("bidPrice", paddedLower, paddedHigher, true, true).And().Field("__Path", programParent.MultipleCharacterWildcard()).And().GroupedOr(new[] {"description", "nodename"}, q.Fuzzy()).Compile();
```